# Arguments in a function

Tags: python, parameters, arguments

I understand that when defining a function, you can provide a parameter, like so:

```
def func(lst):
    # code
```

I also understand that when you are defining a function, you can provide multiple parameters using the *args syntax, like so:

```
def func(*lst):
    # code
```

I have a problem where I have to define a function that sorts a list and removes any duplicates.

Here's what I did:

```
def func(lst):
    return sorted(set(lst))
```

The website that I was doing this practice problem (edabit.com) tested my code, like so:

```
Test.assert_equals(func([1, 3, 3, 5, 5]), [1, 3, 5])
```

The test ran successfully, and my code was correct. But here's where I got confused, the test provided multiple parameters (1, 3, 3, 5, 5), I didn't use the *args syntax, yet somehow it ran successfully.

Isn't it supposed to give me an error, saying something like func() takes exactly 1 argument (5 given)?

When I provided the *args syntax, it told me TypeError: unhashable type:'list'

My guess is that this probably happened because the test didn't call the function, instead they used the assert keyword. Is my guess correct?

Comment: If you define your function with `def func(lst):` then it will take a single parameter; if you define it as `def func(*lst):` then it will take a variable number of parameters from the caller and combine them into a single parameter in the function.  (In fact it is a tuple, so in fact `lst` is a slightly confusing variable name.)  In this case you are passing a list, not multiple parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you gave a single argument of type list. If you have
`a = [1,2,3,4]`
You have a list
Calling
`f(a)`
And `f([1, 2,3,4])` is the same
Notice the [ brackets.
If, however, you were too call `f(1, 2,3,4)`, that would be a mistake.

Also: the assert keyword still calls the function. It has no way of not calling it, as it has been put in as an expression.
if you call f(g(5))
Then f is already called with the result of g, not the function call itself.

Answer (score 1):

You passed in a list of numbers, which is one argument:

```
func([1, 3, 3, 5, 5])
```

vs.

```
func(1, 3, 3, 5, 5)
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like they only did pass a single parameter to your function.

```py
Test.assert_equals(func([1, 3, 3, 5, 5]), [1, 3, 5]))
```

The array `[1, 3, 3, 5, 5]` is passed as the single argument to `func()`, then the array `[1, 3, 5]` is passed as the second argument to `assert_equals()`.